# Os dados não aparecem na página

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos, mysqli, classes, wamp

Fiz um código OO em PHP. Usei MySQLi para o banco e WAMPSERVER como servidor, no qual inseri dados para a tabela "categoria". O collation do banco é "latin2_general_ci".
Não ocorreram erros, mas no navegador os dados cadastrados não apareceram.
Abaixo está o código:

```
<?php
$conecta = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste_forum");
if($conecta->connect_error){
die("Connection failed: " . $conecta->connect_error);
}


class categoria{

    private $id;
    private $titulo;

    /*public function conexao($conecta){
        $conecta = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "teste_forum");
    }*/

    public function setId($id){
        $this->id  = $id;
        }

    public function getId(){
        return $this->id;
        }

    public function setTitulo($titulo){
        $this->titulo = $titulo;
        }

    public function getTitulo(){
        return $this->titulo;
        }

    function listar(categoria $categoria){
        try{
            global $conecta;
            $query = $conecta->query("SELECT titulo FROM categoria");
            return $query;
            /*$rs = $query->fetch_assoc();
            $categoria->setTitulo($rs["titulo"]);*/
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo "ERRO!";
        }
    }

    function inserir(categoria $categoria){
        try{
            global $conecta;
            $query = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO categoria (titulo)    VALUES (?)") or die ($conecta->error);
            $query->bind_param("s", getTitulo());
            $query->execute();
            if ($query->affected_rows > 0){
                return true;    
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo "ERRO!";
        }
    }

}

?>

   <html>
   <head>
   <meta charset="utf-8">
   <style type="text/css">

     h3{
      color: red;
     }

     h4{
       color: steelblue;
     }

     form{
       border: 1px #333 solid;
     }

    .nome{
       color: green;
     }

    .coment{
      color: violet;
     }

 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php


     $categoria = new Categoria;
     $cat_listar = $categoria->listar($categoria);

     while($reg = $cat_listar->fetch_array()){
          echo "<h3>......... " . $categoria->getTitulo($reg["titulo"]) . ".........</h3>";
     }

?>

<br><br>
<a href="form.php">Ir ao formul�rio cadastrar categorias</a>
```

Na figura abaixo destaco que eu queria que o navegador mostrasse os títulos.

[image: Figura 1 - Dados da tabela categoria]

E a outra figura abaixo mostra o resultado. Os títulos tinham que estar entre os pontinhos vermelhos.

[image: Figura 2 - Resultado...não esperado]

Tudo que eu quero é que os títulos fossem exibidos.

Answer (score 1):

[fetch_array()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) devolve um array, se o objeto categoria não tem nenhuma validação ou formatação apenas faça o echo com `$reg` é a forma mais simples.

```
echo '<h3>'. $reg[0] .'</h3>';

//também é possível imprirmir o nome através de índice não númerico

echo '<h3>'. $reg['titulo'] .'</h3>';
```

`getTitulo()` não recebe parâmetro parece que você confundiu com `setTitulo()`, no código abaixo em nenhum momento foi feita atribuição dos valores.

```
 $categoria = new Categoria;
 $cat_listar = $categoria->listar($categoria);

 while($reg = $cat_listar->fetch_array()){
      echo "<h3>" . $categoria->getTitulo($reg["titulo"]) . "</h3>";
 }
```

Para o método `listar()` retornar um array de categoria(objeto) faça a seguinte modificação

```
public function listar(){
   global $conecta;

   $query = $conecta->query($query);
   $arr = array();

   while($item = $query->fetch_array()){
      $c = new categoria();
      $c->setTitulo($item[0]);
      $arr[] = $c;
   }

   return $arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Incrementei a função inserir():

```
 function inserir(categoria $categoria){
        try{
            global $conecta;
            $query = $conecta->prepare("INSERT INTO categoria (titulo) VALUES (?)") or die ($conecta->error);
            $query->bind_param("s", setTitulo());
            $query->execute();
            if ($query->affected_rows > 0){
                return true;    
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $e){
            echo "ERRO!";
        }
    }
```

Assim eu pude usar o laço de repetição abaixo:

```
    while($reg = $cat_listar->fetch_array()){
    echo "<h3>......... " . $reg["titulo"] . ".........</h3>";
}
```

E deu certo:

[image: Resultado esperado]

Comment: Como funcionou? nesta linha `$query->bind_param("s", setTitulo());` `setTitulo()` não retorna nada, ela faz é inserir um titulo a propriedade $titulo do objeto.

Comment: É porque eu só queria que o SELECT funcione, mas obrigada assim pelo aviso.